# String or binary data would be truncated with entityframework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a really strange issue with entity framework 6.1.0, Sql server 2008 SP2

```
 public virtual void Insert(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

            this.Entities.Add(entity);

            this._context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
          ..
        }
    }
```

Table GenericAttribute

```
Id  int  (primary key, auto increment)
EntityId    int 
KeyGroup    nvarchar(400)   
[Key]   nvarchar(400)   
Value   nvarchar(MAX)   
StoreId int
```

1st insert: (1588,"Customer","FullName","abd cde", 0) => inserted

2nd insert   => inserted

3rd insert: (1588,"Customer","LastName","aaa bbb", 0) => String or binary data would be truncated error !! why ??

i tried to input manually on the database with the above value, work just fine. really panic now.

The value is so short, how come it must be truncated ??

Comment: Try to use the profiler on SQL Server and see what is the exact query getting generated against your data.

Comment: "Auto increment" with ms-SQL? Shouldn't that be IDENTITY?

Comment: Show relevant code. How do you generate the entities you want to insert?